How to merge several .warc files into one?
I have 17 warc files directing one website and they're all 1GB in size. How can I merge them into a single .warc file so I can get the whole content of the website in one file?
I have tried the 'type' command in windows and the output file only refer to about 10 htmls which is far less than the original ones.
plus, I unzip the warc.gz files to get the warc files which can be correctly recognized by the ReplayWeb
I'm a fully starter about the things. Thank you for your help!

Just concatenate the WARC files, no matter whether still gzipped or not:
cat 1st.warc.gz 2nd.warc.gz >all.warc.gz

cat 1st.warc 2nd.warc >all.warc

Both - all.warc.gz and all.warc - are valid WARC files.
One note about gzipped WARC files: the WARC standard recommends record-level compression. As a consequence, compressing an uncompressed WARC files requires specific tools. For example warcio or FastWARC provide a "recompress" utility. All WARC tools should support reading record-level compressed WARC files, including Replay Webpage.
